# Why does the three counting methods give different results?

Tags: python, vim

I have a text file and I want to count how many lines it it. I have different results:

1. wc -l myfile.tsv
2. vim myfile.tsv
3. Python code:

   ```
   total_count = 0
   with open('myfile.tsv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
       for index, line in enumerate(f):
           total_count += 1
   print(total_count)
   ```

Both 1) and 2) gives the same count: 13200096, but 3) gives a different number: 13201169

Each line is delimited by tabs with 4 columns. Which one is more accurate and what's wrong somewhere?

BTW, why does the stackoverflow's automatical formatting stop working?

Comment: Are you sure you are looping over the lines? Try:
for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines()): 
    total_count += 1 
print(total_count)

Comment: There is no such thing as "stackoverflow's automatical formatting". If you want your question to look right, you have to make it look right yourself.

Comment: @romainl I usually click the code tag and it will be formatted, but today it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: @chatax In Python to loop over each line in a file, the readlines() isn't necessary. And I also tried the readlines(), it gives the same result. No help

Comment: No idea, Markdown is too easy so I never use the formatting bar. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Maybe there are some empty lines that python does read, but 1 and 2 do not count. total_count += len([line for line in f.readlines() if line])

Comment: @chatax Doesn't help with "if line" checking. I suspect it may have something to do the with tag delimiter?

Comment: In response to accuracy: I'd trust `wc` over the other methods especially over an untested, custom, python script no matter how simple.

Comment: 'What do you mean by untested, custom' script?

Comment: @MichaelRuth you're probably right but one caveat with `wc` is that it doesn't count lines, it counts newlines. `printf 'Hello World' | wc -l` will output `0`, for example. The OP hasn't shown us the contents of a minimal version of `myfile.tsv` that can reproduce the problem, so it's all just guesswork so far. For all we know `myfile.tsv` isn't even a POSIX text file.

Comment: @marlon use divide-and-conquer to get your file down to a minimal version (say 5 lines) than can reproduce your problem and [edit] your question to show that so we can help you. Chances are by doing that exercise you'll figure out the issue yourself and not need any help though.

Comment: Could reading the file as UTF8-encoded in Python (assuming that's what `encoding='utf8'` means - I don't know Python well) vs plain text in the other tools make a difference?